# Force pair of attributes to be unique

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have a model which contains relationships between a user and his contacts.

Here is the current code for this model :

```
module.exports = {

  connection: 'mysqlServer',

  attributes: {

    user: {
      model: 'user',
      required: true
    },

    contact: {
      model: 'user',
      required: true
    }

  }
};
```

What I would like is to make the combo `user` and `contact` uniques. That means that there may be several identical users and several identical contacts but only one user with a specific contact (ie: we can have `user=1, contact=1` and `user=1, contact=2`, but we can't have `user=1, contact=1` and `user=1, contact=1`).

The unique validation property is not enough to create the validation I want.

Do you have an idea how I should proceed? With custom validation rules maybe?